# Magnetic Sensors out there

Tags: sensor

Is anyone aware of a sensor which can detect materials which are attracted to a magnet?
I am aware of a reed and a hall effect sensor, but they are used to detect magnets.

I am looking for something like a reed, but with magnetic wire (which switches), and can turn on/off if there is a metal in vicinity (which can be attracted by a magnet).

Comment: So you want to make a metal detector?

Comment: Yes, there are many people that are aware of such things.  However, who knows what is off topic here.

Comment: It's customary in English to place a space before opening parenthesis. I've edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a [reluctance sensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_reluctance_sensor), which is commonly used to detect speeds of rotating machinery. Antilock brake systems are a common application.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to detect the metals and the type of the metal.

1. Inductive - all ferromagnetic materials will increase the inductance of near placed inductor with open magnetic circuit. So, if you get such inductor and measure its inductance you can detect the presence of such materials. (BTW, paramagnetic metals cause decreasing of the inductance).
2. Magnetic - if there is a hall-sensor and near placed permanent magnet, the presence of the metal object will change the intensity of the magnetic field that can be detected by the sensor.
3. Variable reluctance sensor - It is suitable only for a moving metal objects. Consists of a inductor and permanent magnet that sets permanent magnetic field in the inductor core. The nearly moving ferromagnetic object will cause change of the magnetic field and will induce a voltage pulse in the inductor. These sensors are often used in the car electronics to detect the cams on the timing disk of the crankshaft and for the ABS systems. Extremely robust.